# Navbar Bootsrap 4 doesn't toggle (scss?)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, toggle, navbar

I have customize my bootstrap. Everything works except navbar toggle. You can view my website at http://www.ideastud.io.

## Intro

I have 4 SCSS to customize bootstrap:

- common_begin (to customize grid-breakpoints, override variables, ...)
- theme1 (to customize colors and add theme1 styles)
- theme2 (to customize colors and add theme2 styles)
- common_end (to add classes or customize bootstrap classes for both themes)

On my HTML code, I use theme1 or theme2 (compiled by gulp). Theme1 and theme2 have the same hierarchy:

```
// override bootstrap variables

// import common styles 
@import "common_begin.scss";

// import some bootstrap :
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss";
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss";

@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";

// theme styles
@import "theme1.scss";
```

> I don't think bootstrap generation is the cause of the problem below.

## Issue

In my layout, I have a navbar... and the toggler does not work... I don't know why (Yet this is not the first time that I implement bootstrap) :

```html
<header>
    <a class="d-flex justify-content-center" href="/">
        <img src="/images/logo-ideastudio.png" height="50" class="d-inline-block align-top m-1" alt="">
    </a>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" asp-page="/">Accueil</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" asp-page="/go/olymp">Olymp</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" asp-page="/go/team">Equipe</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" asp-page="/go/expertises">Expertises</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" asp-page="/go/trainings">Formations</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" asp-page="/go/projects">Clients</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" asp-page="/go/about">À propos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

## Resolution attempts

### Change the list approach

And because [bootstrap] use classes for their `nav`s, [we] can avoid the list-based approach entirely if you like (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#nav), I have try to replace `ul`/`li` by `div`s, like this:

```html
<header>
    <a class="d-flex justify-content-center" href="/">
        <img src="/images/logo-ideastudio.png" height="50" class="d-inline-block align-top m-1" alt="">
    </a>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Accueil</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/go/olymp">Olymp</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/go/team">&Eacute;quipe</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/go/expertises">Expertises</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/go/trainings">Formations</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/go/projects">Clients</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/go/press">Presse</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/go/about">About</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Deliberately, I have not a Navbar brand.

### Check some essentials

I have the same id for data-target attribute, etc. I have paste the original sample on about (à propos) page if you want to try. I think I have already check all steps... I you have an Idea...

### Update

I have tried to update bootstrap 4.2.1 to 4.3.1

Comment: for customize breakpoints you need to set it manually by `$grid-breakpoints: ()`

Comment: Yes I know, but that's not the problem. The real problem is that the toggle button does not work...

Comment: I use ASP.NET Core, it would seem that jQuery is not loaded... And I don't know why (I've tried with local copy and with a cdn)

Comment: I've try with using a CDN to laod jQuery... jQuery is ready but the navbar still not working...

Comment: why its not working, do you add bootstrap js on that ?

Comment: @NishargShah yes, of course. You can read the code here: http://ideastud.io

Comment: I see your code but i cant find any problem in navbar !! I think you have problem in JS file !!

Comment: You are changing many style and scripts of bootstrap